# Qt for Python QCoreApplication: How to Exit non-GUI application

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a small non-GUI application that basically starts an event loop, connects a signal to a slot, and emits a signal. I would like the slot to stop the event loop and exit the application.

However, the application does not exit.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to exit from the event loop?

Python 3.7.0

Qt for Python (PySide2) 5.12.0

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class ConsoleTest(QtCore.QObject):
    all_work_done = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConsoleTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.run_test()

    def run_test(self):
        self.all_work_done.connect(self.stop_test)
        self.all_work_done.emit("foo!")

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def stop_test(self, msg):
        print(f"Test is being stopped, message: {msg}")
        # neither of the next two lines will exit the application.
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()
        # QtCore.QCoreApplication.exit(0)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = ConsoleTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your code calls `quit()` before entering the event-loop.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  However, I feel I am missing something fundamental.  I thought ConsoleTest() was running in the event loop.  I am unsure as to the  changes I need to do to make this happen.  I tried to figure this out from both the API and the usual searches.  What have I missed?

Comment: The line `mainwindow = ConsoleTest()` is executed before the line that starts the event-loop. There's no real mystery to it. Just hand-trace the code (and/or add some debugging print statements) and you will see for yourself exactly what is happening. Nothing ever runs "in" the event-loop (not exactly sure what you mean by that) - perhaps you need to read [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `app.exec_()` you are entering the Qt event loop, but since you are executing the code that call `quit()` at the moment the object is being initialized, your application will never quit.

I can think of two options to achieve the "exit" process you want to do:

- Just call `sys.exit(1)` inside the `stop_test()` instead of a `quit` or `exit` call, or
- you use [singleShot](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) to quit the application:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class ConsoleTest(QtCore.QObject):
    all_work_done = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConsoleTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.run_test()

    def run_test(self):
        self.all_work_done.connect(self.stop_test)
        self.all_work_done.emit("foo!")

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def stop_test(self, msg):
        print(f"Test is being stopped, message: {msg}")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, QtCore.qApp.quit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = ConsoleTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```